# Essayer: j'essaie, or j'essaye?

Tags: verbes, conjugaison

I was confused how I should conjugate the verb **essayer**, or any other ones like **nettoyer**.

I looked up in a conjugation website,

> J'essaie / ye

I'm guessing that means both **j'essaie** and **j'essaye** are accepted. However, my teacher said to use **j'essaie**.

Which one is correct? If both are accepted, is there any difference?

Comment: In newspaper and other media, you will find: essaie. Go with what your teacher said.

Comment: Yes, even if both are correct, the -aie form is much more common.

Comment: Do you guys have hard data about that?

Comment: According to ngram, the they are [very close](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=essaye%2C+essaie&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cessaye%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cessaie%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I think it's due to the fact that you chose "English"... if you choose "French" for the "corpus", then the result is significantly different...

Comment: @Frank Ah autant pour moi, j'avais pas remarqué qu'il choisissait "english" par défaut.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like both are in regular use today, and that this is also the case for "payer", "balayer", as well as any other verb in "-ayer". I am not aware of any rule mandating to use one rather than the other when writing vs. speaking.

The pronunciation is slightly different though: "j'essaye" would sound at the end like "pareil", whereas "j'essaie" would sound like "sait".

I am not aware that one pronunciation or the other would have this or that connotation. It is even possible for native speakers to use both in the same conversation.